# Multi Parameter Search in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API with EF Core, and I am wondering how you would search when the user can search by multiple optional parameters.

For example, a user would search a list of users by specifying age and gender, so it only returns results that match both columns, or if they only specify age, it would only return results that match that one specified column

Update: I figured it out

```
var result = _dbContext.Sample .Where(sample => userId.IsNullOrEmpty() ? true : EF.Functions.Like(sample.User, $"%{userId}%") && sampleNo.IsNullOrEmpty() ? true : EF.Functions.Like(sample.SampleNumber, $"%{sampleNo}%")
```

Comment: What kind of query are you trying to build? Multiple `AND`s are easy, ORs require help from LinqKit.

Comment: Have you gotten started on this? can you share some code for the search or at least the data structure you are searching against? There are myriad ways to do this, but many of those ways may not work depending on your code or data structure or other constraints.

Comment: var result = _dbContext.Sample .Where(sample => userId.IsNullOrEmpty() ? true : EF.Functions.Like(sample.User, $"%{userId}%") && sampleNo.IsNullOrEmpty() ? true : EF.Functions.Like(sample.SampleNumber, $"%{sampleNo}%")

Comment: So the answers do what you want to achieve. Just replace `==` by `EF.Functions.Like`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the "AND" logic then you can easily build the query dynamically, something like the following:

```
var query = context.User.AsQueriable();

if(filter.Age is not null) // Age is int?
{
   query = query.Where(s => s.Age == filter.Age);
}

if(filter.Gender is not null) // Gender is for example nullable enum
{
   query = query.Where(s => s.Gender == filter.Gender);
}

// ...
```

For "OR" logic you can leverage something like [`LINQKit`](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)'s [`PredicateBuilder`](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#predicatebuilder) or build [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/) manually.

Answer (score -1):

I use something like `(age==null ||x.Age == age)`. You could try this

```
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MyContext _context;

        public UsersController(MyContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("/search")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> SearchUser(string? name,int? age,string? gender)
        {
            var users =await _context.User.Where(x =>(name==null||x.Name == name) &&(age==null ||x.Age == age) &&(gender==null|| x.Gender == gender)).ToListAsync();
            return users;
        }
    }
```

The table
[image]

Test

[image]
[image]

Comment: Such [catch-all](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) queries results in bad execution plans and just aren't needed in LINQ. You can append expressions at runtime

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Generally speaking that's correct, but EF-core skips the predicates in the query during the query translation process when `== null` is true. (EF6 doesn't).

Comment: @GertArnold when was this added? It certainly wasn't in the first versions. This should be added to the answer, to specify which versions it applies to. I'd still be wary of any complexity limitations that would cause EF Core to emit a catch-all.

Comment: I can look back down to EFC 3. There it works as I described.

Comment: But I agree that it should be part of the answer. Moreover, IMO this shouldn't have been answered before OP would have answered your question and after that there's no doubt that the question can be marked as duplicate.