# How to convert Func<T, bool> to Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core, expression, expression-trees

I use this code but it gets an error that:

> Error: System.ArgumentException: Expression of type '...GreenPaperItem' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure' of method 'Boolean

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression<T>(Func<T, bool> p)
{
     ParameterExpression p0 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
     ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(bool));
     return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Call(p.Method, p0, p1),
           new ParameterExpression[] { p0, p1 });
}
```

the expression is intended to be used in a linq to entities IQueriyable query:

```
 query = query.Where(ToExpression<GreenPaperItem>(filter.GenerateFilterFunction()));
```

Comment: In short - you don't. It still sill not be translatable.

Comment: Also please provide a [mre]

Comment: Assuming you have the runtime delegate (`Func<T, bool>`), it's compiled, all you have is its signature and the stream of CIL opcodes. There's no easy way to recompile it to a syntax tree (which is what the `Expression...` is). This can be done by the compiler, at the compile time.

Comment: You can do it the other way around. Expressions have a ```.Compile``` method.

Comment: @Max `Compile` does the opposite of what the goal is.

Comment: so query = query.Where(filter.GenerateFilterFunction()).AsQueryable(); works? it is mudblazor.

Comment: I used AsQueryable() and it works, but for checking that it is not enumerable at the end, I get the error "The given 'IQueryable' does not support generation of query strings."
when I want to convert the query ToQueryString()

Comment: _" it is mudblazor"_ - it is not that relevant here. And it will not change how queryables and queryable providers work (EF Core one specifically).

Comment: What does `GenerateFilterFunction` do, please show.

Comment: @GuruStron I know i said 'the other way around' wether or not thats useful depends. If you have control over it and the performance hit of compiling an expression tree at runtime does not matter do it the other way around or it will get complicated. The accepted awnser also states the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to convert `Func<T, bool>` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

In short - you don't. The vice versa conversion is "easy" via provided by the framework [`Expression<TDelegate>.Compile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1.compile?view=net-8.0) method. But other way around will require performing something like decompilation from IL/machine code (I think I saw some attempts but not sure where and when =) ).

> I used `AsQueryable()` and it works, but for checking that it is not enumerable at the end, I get the error "The given 'IQueryable' does not support generation of query strings." when I want to convert the query `ToQueryString()`

So basically it does not work (at least in the way you actually want/need too).

It seems that you have some misunderstanding how `IQueryable`, expression trees and query providers (especially EF Core one) work. In short (with some simplifications) usually query provider will analyze the passed expression tree   to perform some actions. In EF Core case it will translate the calls into actual SQL query and it can't translate an arbitrary method call into SQL, which can't be fixed by "converting" `Func<...>` returned by `filter.GenerateFilterFunction()` to `Expression<Func<...>>`.

Your not working attempt:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression<T>(Func<T, bool> p)
{
     ParameterExpression p0 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
     ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(bool));
     return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Call(p.Method, p0, p1),
           new ParameterExpression[] { p0, p1 });
}
```

is not that much different from:

```
query.Where(gpi => filter.GenerateFilterFunction()(gpi)) // allow the compiler to do the magic for you
```

Which will have the same issue - `GenerateFilterFunction` returns the function query provider (EF Core) knows nothing about and can't translate it to SQL (for obvious reasons).

And your attempt from the comments:

```
query = query
   .Where(filter.GenerateFilterFunction())
   .AsQueryable();
```

Will result in that everything since `.Where(filter.GenerateFilterFunction())` will be executed on the client side fetching everything into memory without filtering on the database side ([`Enumerable.Where(Func<>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-8.0) will be used instead of [`Queryable.Where(Expression<Func<>>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-8.0), basically the same effect as explicit `AsEnumerable()` call before `Where`). The following `AsQueryable` does not have any significant effect since it will be queryable over in-memory objects. This is also proved by the observed behavior of [`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToQueryString(IQueryable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-7.0).

You have several options:

1. Introduce `GenerateFilterExpression` method which will actually build translatable `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`
2. Quite usual approach is to just leverage ability to "dynamically" compose `Where`'s (when you need AND combination logic):

   ```
   if(filter.IsProp1Provided)
   {
       query = query.Where(e => e.Col1 == filter.Prop1);
   }

   if(filter.IsAnotherPropProvided)
   {
       query = query.Where(e => e.AnotherCol == filter.AnotherProp);
   }
   ```
3. Use [`PredicateBuilder` from LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit?tab=readme-ov-file#predicatebuilder) (possibly in addition to point 2)

See also:

- [What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252785/2501279)
- [Multi Parameter Search in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76955831/2501279)
- [Expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/)
- I highly recommend enabling [EF Core logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/#simple-logging) for development environments to monitor what is actually happening.
- [EF Core: Database Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/database-functions) - has links to supported method calls to SQL translation for several databases.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library [ExTree](https://github.com/kostat/XLinq) that does the requested conversion.
Note that it does not handle complex constructs like switch or try blocks.

It has also a sister library - EntityLinq, that allows you to write type safe "SQL using C#" and target EF Core. Under the hood it uses the above [ExTree](https://github.com/kostat/XLinq) to first convert Funcs/Methods to Expressions and then Expressions to the SQL.